# how to create new custom options type in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

How do I create new product custom options type in magento?

For example, I have to give new image a custom option type in magento which fetches an image from my custom module table, and I want to assign that image to my custom options image field.

Comment: For an answer see this article: http://www.webmasterbulletin.net/2011/04/magento-programmatically-add-custom-options/1417 as well as the following question on updating custom options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798158/how-to-update-custom-options-programatically-in-magento

Comment: yes this create new custom options for products not new custom options type like there is a custom options select and now i want to create new custom options type image

Comment: Sorry – I misunderstood the question first…

Comment: Been working on this myself, and it is incredibly tricky. It requires some rewrites to core files. It could take many hours, and a lot of deep knowledge of Magento. The four types are fairly hard-coded in. I've been trying to add a fifth type to allow customers to pick a custom "size" in square feet, and it is very difficult. Just wanted to let you know since no one has been replying, it's because it is very tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot this question but i need again to create new custom option type in my another project. I had Created new custom options type using this link. 
http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/custom-input-types-custom-options

Solution is bit lengthy and its not possible to put whole code here, so i have just share this link, going through this link i had create new custom options type easily, explanation is good  in this article.

I have modify some changes for my need .

Hope this will help some one.

As Dustin Graham said its incredibly tricky.

Answer (score 4):

As Dustin Graham said, it is very tricky. First steps:

1. Add new node under `global/catalog/product/options/custom/groups`. See examples in `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml`.
2. Create new block to render your custom option.
3. Rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option` and implement saving your custom type options (`saveOptions()` method) and loading your custom type options (`getProductOptionCollection` method).

If your custom type isn't very custom :) - it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

@Mufaddal thanks for sharing this link. I'd like to offer an alternative to this since it requires quite a bit knowledge.

If you're only trying to change the way a specific dropdown (for example) is displayed you can also overwrite the `/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml` as follows:

`
    
    getOption() ?>

```
<dt><label<?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo  $this->escapeHtml($_option->getTitle()) ?></label>    </dt>
<dd<?php if ($_option->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
<div class="input-box">
    <?php echo $this->getValuesHtml(); ?>

    <?php if($_option->option_id == 2) : ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery('#select_2').css('display', 'none');
                </script>

                <?php foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) { ?>
                    <?php echo $_value->getTitle(); // the title of the option ?>
                    <?php echo $_value->getOptionTypeId(); // the id ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <!-- add custom code that triggers select in the background -->

            <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($_option->getIsRequire()): ?>
        <?php if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO || $_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX): ?>
            <span id="options-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-container"></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

`

You can then hide the select and interact with the select through jQuery.