# How to update custom options programatically in magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7, product

I have lot of products with custom options, now I have requirement to update only custom options through csv file. so how we can do this programatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found one solution for updating custom options programatically here is the solution

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$values = array();
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
           $p = $o->getValues();
        }
    }
  foreach($p as $v)
        {
            $values[$v->getId()]['option_type_id']= $v->getId();
                $values[$v->getId()]['title']= 'test';
                $values[$v->getId()]['price']= 23;
                $values[$v->getId()]['price_type']= 'fixed';
                $values[$v->getId()]['sku']= $value1;

          }
        $v->setValues($values);
        $v->saveValues();
$product->save();
```

hope this help someone
this only update custom options value

Answer (score 5):

I think this is also useful...

If you are customize the products .

```
<?php

$magePath = 'app/Mage.php'; 

require_once $magePath;

Varien_Profiler::enable(); 

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product_ids = array(1,2,167);

$productmodel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) { 

/**i use this two arrays for collecte value because i uses inside setData of 
current option*/

$cos=array();
$co=array();

$product = $productmodel->load($product_id);

$options = $product->getProductOptionsCollection();

if (isset($options)) { 

foreach ($options as $o) { 

$title = $o->getTitle();

/**
this block is for changing information of specific option from collection options inside
current product
the save method for this option in end of code
*/

if ($title == "Line 1/Front") { 

$o->setProduct($product); 

$o->setTitle("Line 1/Ftont"); 

$o->setType("drop_down"); 

$o->setIsRequire(1);

$o->setSortOrder(0);


}

/**
this block for update or add information of specific value inside current option
*/

$optionType = $o->getType(); 

//test type

if ($optionType == "drop_down") { 

//getting collection of value related to current option

$values = $o->getValuesCollection(); 

$found = false; 

foreach ($values as $k => $v) { 

//test existing of value for update

if (1 == preg_match("/said$/i", $v->getTitle())) { 

//update and save

$v->setTitle("morad")

->setSku("kk")

->setPriceType("fixed")

->setSortOrder(0)

->setPrice(floatval(13.0000));

$v->setOption($o)->save();

/**
this ligne is important i collecte all value required for normalize save function 
related to current option
*/

$cos[]=$v->toArray($co);

} 
} 


/**
create new value object you can use $option->getValueInstance() for working with 
getSingleton
*/

$value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value'); 

$value->setOption($o) 

->setTitle('valueiwant') 

->setSku("nn")

->setPriceType("fixed")

->setSortOrder(1)

->setPrice(12)

/**
this ligne is important (relation forigien key) for related this new value
to specific option
*/

->setOptionId($o->getId());

$value->save();

/**
this ligne is important i collecte all value required for normalize save function   
related to current option
*/

$cos[]=$value->toArray($co);
} 


$o->setData("values",$cos)->save();

//var_dump($cos);

}


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you create a module to do that ? If you do, you must use the cron system of Magento and call a method of a custom model :

```
<config>
    <!--...-->
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <company_test>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0,15,30,45 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>test/testmodel::testMethod</model>
                </run>
            </company_module>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

When this is done, you can update the option of a specific product by using the model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option`. I don't know how the CSV is made, but the algorithm can be something like that :

```
// foreach option
/** @var $opt Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option */
$opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
$opt->setProduct($product);

$optionArray = array(
    'is_delete' => 0,
    'title' => 'Blabla',
    'previous_group' => '',
    'previous_type' => '',
    'type' => 'field',  //can be radio, drop_down, file, area...
    'is_require' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 42,
    'values' => array()
);

$opt->addOption($optionArray);
$opt->saveOptions();
// end foreach
```

Also check this link : http://subesh.com.np/2009/12/adding-custom-options-product-magento/

Comment: yes, what this create new options, but i want to update value of options, suppose i have options created if options's value is changed then update options value otherwise create new options field

Comment: Then you have to use other methods from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option`. It seems that there's no method to update in one step, but you can compare the list of your options and your values from Magento to the ones from you CSV. Or you can directly use SQL to change them, in the table `catalog_product_option`.