# Magento Customize product custom options

Tags: e-commerce, magento-1.7, magento

I am working on magento. I want to add drop-down menu at product detail page. For this i tried custom options at product configuration  in back-end. But now problem is that i have more than 10 drop down  menus each has more than 20 option values.It is not possible to add them manually at the time of create new product.
Is there any way to add option values of drop-down in custom options from code.
now i have following questions:-
**1. How to add drop-down list option values from code or any other way.
2. how to add custom options automatically when add new product.**

Please reply asap.If there is any other way to do this please mention here.

Answer (score 1):

try below link for creating and updating custom options programmatically
http://subesh.com.np/2009/12/adding-custom-options-product-magento/

[How to update custom options programatically in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798158/how-to-update-custom-options-programatically-in-magento/)

Comment: thanx for your reply. Can u please tell me that where should i write those code which is given in this link  http://subesh.com.np/2009/12/adding-custom-options-product-magento/

Comment: you can create observer for event product_save_after there you can add this code of creating custom options for product